# mathematical simulation of svm workings

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, svm

i cant seem to work my head around the mathematical part of svm
i understand the concept and the derivations but the the part that comes after lagrangian formulation is where im stuck..(googling didn't help at all)

a manual calculation of w and b would be great (taking a few random points and separating them using support vectors)

Comment: Many flavours of SVM are equivalent to classic convex optimization problems. Maybe refreshing the general knowledge of convex optimization will help. One reference: Boyd, S., & Vandenberghe, L. (2004). Convex Optimization. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: I did check out the book.. it's very informative but it's not what I was looking for